# Does the following integral depending on $\alpha$ converge : $\int_{R^2} \frac{1}{(1+x^4+y^4)^\alpha}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Does the following integral depending on $\alpha$ converge : $$\int_{R^2} \frac{1}{(1+x^4+y^4)^\alpha}$$ ?

I know that for $\alpha \le 0$ it diverges. It is pretty trivial since you can compare the function to $1$.

For $\alpha \ge 0$ I tried to change to polar coordinates and I got to 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{rdr}{(1+\frac{r^4}{2}(2-sin^2(2\theta))^\alpha}$$

I'm not pretty sure how to continue from here. I think I can bound it from both sides since $0 \le sin^2(2\theta) \le 1$ . I don't know exactly for which values of $\alpha$ I should use each bound.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a wider view of the situation: clearly the problem of convergence, if any, occurs when $r\to\infty$, and then, $$1+x^4+y^4\approx r^4$$ hence the integral converges iff $$\int_1^\infty\frac1{(r^4)^\alpha}rdr$$ converges, that is, iff $$\alpha>\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me